# If i run compiz --replace, all border and button of the window disappear

Tags: compiz

i would like to run compiz on my s.o.
The problem is that if i run 'compiz --replace', compiz start, but the upper border of the window (with minimize, maximize button) disappear!
I try to run also: gtk-window-decorator --replace but without success.

How could be the problem ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've had success in rebooting or logging out. You want to restart the x-server and load compiz as your window manager. Which version Ubuntu?

Comment: Me no! No reboot or logging solve the situation!

Answer (score 0):

Place fusion-icon on start session programs in compiz manager on border option change the border command to `gtk-window-decorator --replace and end session`

or the best way: go to

http://iamfuss.deviantart.com/journal/Install-emerald-for-Ubuntu-12-04-292806813

proceed the install and in compiz manager on border option change the border command to emerald --replace and you will be happy.